# launch file for another machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do a single master. My ssh password-less is working just by typing as follow: **ssh huey@10.42.0.3**

**IP of A is 10.42.0.2**

master is A

**IP of B is 10.42.0.3**

```
<launch>

<machine 
    name = "robot" 
    address = "huey@10.42.0.3" 
    env-loader = "/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh"></machine>
<node
    pkg ="turtlesim" 
    type = "turtlesim_node"
    name="turtlesim"
    machine = "robot"></node>

</launch>
```

but i got this error

```
cannot resolve host address for machine [huey@10.42.0.3]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222553/launch-file-for-another-machine/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding the user and address separately:

```
<machine 
name = "robot" 
address = "10.42.0.3" 
user = "huey"
env-loader = "/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh"></machine>
```

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-17**:
Hi chrissi, It gives other issue after this.
remote[10.42.0.3-0]: failed to launch on master:
10.42.0.3 is not in your SSH known_hosts file.
Please manually:
ssh huey@10.42.0.3
then try roslaunching again.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-12-17**:
This should solve that issue: http://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file/

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-17**:
Chrissi I almost got it to work. Based on the link you have me, this is what i put in the terminal:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa' 10.42.0.3
```

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-17**:
But there is new error:

```
[10.42.0.3-0]: [turtlesim-1] process has died [pid 2638, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/turtlesim`/turtlesim_node `__name:=turtlesim __log:=/home/huey/.ros/log/e75e45ec-a500-11e5-9a9d-f4b7e29bc4b5/turtlesim-1.log].`
```

when i do the roslaunch on my master laptop.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-12-18**:
Can you run the turtlesim on the other machine without the ssh setup? Also, turtlesim does need a graphical user interface. I don't think that X forwarding will mwork like that. Try `DISPLAY=:0 roslaunch ...` which might then start the GUI on the remote machine instead of trying to forward it.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-12-18**:
Never tried this though. If this doesn't work, start the turtlesim on the local machine.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-12-18**:
No, this won't work... I don't think you can start nodes that require X remotely using a launch file but I might be mistaken.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-18**:
i see. I will just do a basic talker listener from ROS tutorial rather than turtlesim.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-18**:
you are right turtlesim does not work work remotely.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-18**:
Here is the new `roslaunch`;

```
<launch>

<machine 
    name = "slave"
    address = "10.42.0.3"
    user = "huey"
    env-loader = "/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh"></machine>

<node
    pkg ="talker" 
    type = "talker"
    name="talker"
    machine = "slave"</node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-12-18**:
i get this error now:

```
[10.42.0.3-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [talker/talker.cpp]: talker
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

i am almost there Chrissi